# Let x be a continuous variable..Find $f_Y(y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X be a continuous random variable with PDF $$ f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}. $$ and let $ Y = \sqrt{\mid x \mid}$, find $f_Y(y)$.

I know that the formula is $f_Y(y) = \sum\limits_{I=1}^n \frac{f_X(x)}{\mid g’(x) \mid}$

And $g’(x) = \frac{x}{2\mid x \mid^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

And $x=y^2$, but the result I’m getting is crazy so is this the right approach? $\frac{f_X(y^2)}{\mid g’(y^2) \mid} \cdot 2 = f_Y(y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is immediate that $Y\geq0$ so that $f_Y(y)=0$ for negative $y$.

You can find the CDF of $Y$ by stating that for $y\geq0$:$$F_Y(y)=\mathsf P(Y\leq y)=\mathsf P(-y^2\leq X\leq y^2)=F_X(y^2)-F_X(-y^2)$$

Here PDF $f_X$ is the derivative of $F_X$.

Now you can find $f_Y$ as derivative of $F_Y$.

Comment: so that would be: $$ f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^4}{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{-y^4}{2}}$$ ??

Comment: No. With chain-rule you find $f_Y(y)=f_X(y^2)2y-f_X(-y^2)(-2y)$. Work that out.